# php multiple dimension array to father child relationship array

Tags: php, arrays, parent-child, relationship

I have a multiple dimension array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14061
            [subchannel] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14144
                            [subchannel] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14154
                                            [subchannel] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [name] => 14154name
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14155
                                            [subchannel] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [name] => 14155name
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14156
                                            [subchannel] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [name] => 14156name
                                        )                             
                                )
                            [name] => 14144name
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14145
                            [subchannel] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14161
                                            [subchannel] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [name] => 14161name
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14162
                                            [subchannel] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [name] => 14162name
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14163
                                            [subchannel] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [name] => 14163name
                                        )                                 
                                )
                            [name] => 14145name
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14146
                            [subchannel] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14167
                                            [subchannel] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [name] => 14167name
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14168
                                            [subchannel] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [name] => 14168name
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14169
                                            [subchannel] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [name] => 14169name
                                        )                                  
                                )

                            [name] => 14146name
                        )                   

                )

            [name] => 14061name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14062
            [subchannel] => Array
                (
                )

            [name] => 14062name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14063
            [subchannel] => Array
                (
                )

            [name] => 14063name
        )

)
```

I want to change the above multiple dimension array to a father-child ralationship array contains this(pid means parentid):

```
[id=>14061,pid=>0,name=>14061name]
[id=>14062,pid=>0,name=>14062name]
[id=>14063,pid=>0,name=>14063name]

[id=>14144,pid=>14061,name=>14144name]
[id=>14145,pid=>14061,name=>14145name]
[id=>14146,pid=>14061,name=>14146name]


[id=>14154,pid=>14144,name=>14154name]
[id=>14155,pid=>14144,name=>14155name]
[id=>14156,pid=>14144,name=>14156name]

[id=>14161,pid=>14145,name=>14161name]
[id=>14162,pid=>14145,name=>14162name]
[id=>14163,pid=>14145,name=>14163name]

[id=>14167,pid=>14146,name=>14167name]
[id=>14168,pid=>14146,name=>14168name]
[id=>14169,pid=>14146,name=>14169name]
```

I use a function  but just get the ids in $this->data:

```
function arr_foreach ($arr) 
    {           
        if (!is_array ($arr)) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($arr as $key => $val ) 
        {
            if (is_array ($val)) 
            {
                $this->arr_foreach ($val);              
            } 
            else 
            {
                if($key == "id"){
                    $this->data[] = $val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

can anybody write a php code to do this?

Comment: Thinking about how popular PHP is, I believe many can - but that is not the point. Do you want help doing this yourself? Then at least please try!

Comment: I am a php newbie, I tried almost half a day.please help.thanks so much.

Comment: This can most likely be done with some interesting recursive functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted attempt is already quite good. However, I would not recurse each array but always skip one level.

What do I mean by that? When you go in the `foreach()` you will have an array of the structure

```
[
  'id' => ..,
  'subchannel' => ..,
  'name' => ..
]
```

Now instead of giving this whole array to the next level of recursion, you can just pass the `subchannel` subarray. The only thing left is knowing the parent's `id`. But this can easily be done by adding another parameter and when recursing passing the current `id` (hence it will be the deeper element's parent).

This leaves you with a function like

```
function flatten($array, $parent = NULL) {
    if (!is_array($array) || empty($array))
        return;

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        //something is wrong/incomplete
        if (!is_array($value) || !isSet($value['id'], $value['subchannel'], $value['name']))
            continue;

        $this->flatten($value['subchannel'], $value['id']);
        $this->data[] = array(
            'id' => $value['id'],
            'pid' => $parent,
            'name' => $value['name']
        );
    }
}
```

Also you will notice that I added the condition `empty($array)`. Since this is here, no additional check is necessary inside the `foreach()` to see if the element actually has children - the next level of recursion will check for that and stop if necessary.